# JavaScript Json Array Parsing using Backbone

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following sample json:

```
{
    "camp": [
        {
            "name": "Name",
            "data": [
                {
                    "date": "04/08/2014",
                    "value": 1000
                },
                {
                    "date": "05/08/2014",
                    "value": 1110
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, I'm able to do: `model.get("camp")[0]`, but when I try: `model.get("camp")[0].get("data")`, I get the following error:

```
undefined is not a function
```

Here model is the standard backbone model which extends `Backbone.Model`
I'm confused what I'm doing wrong !!

Comment: What exactly is `obj` in the first place, what exactly does `obj.get()` return?

Comment: Try this: `obj["camp"][0]["data"]`

Comment: It would be easy to get them like this `obj.camp[0]` or `obj.camp[0]['data']`

Comment: When you say you are able to do `model.get("camp")[0]`, what does it give you? (try a console.log with it). Also, what does `console.log(model["camp"]);` output for you?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to call the model.get() function once. After that, you can treat the returned object just like any other javascript-object. For example, you could do this to get one of the values deep inside the object:

```
model.get("camp")[0].data[0].value
```

To achieve what you are trying to get, do this:

```
model.get("camp")[0].data
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Even if this answer is short, it totally answer the question...

Comment: I've expanded my answer to make it more clear. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to acces a property of your json array, you should simply do like this:

```
var test = json.camp.name
```

Comment: json array? json is just text... you need an object if you want to access any of it

Comment: yep sorry json is just formated text. But i'm sure you can access properties like i wrote.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you get your value:

```
obj.camp[0].data[0]
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Just a newbie.